# Bootstrap 3 navbar layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm a beginner and started to learn bootstrap so please help me for this noob question of mine. I have a problem to my layout in navbar. What I wanted is that the navigation area is on the right and some user information and picture. This is what I wanted my layout to look like.

[image]

So far what I've done is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I've tried nesting containers and added some rows but when the browser collapses, the alignment is destroyed. Can someone please help me? I've been doing this for hours now.

Comment: create jsfiddle ! post css code !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.test{
text-align: center;
}

.top_margin{
margin-top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand top_margin" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class=" test"><a href="#">Username <br> Home | Page 2</a></li>
      <li class="top_margin"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
 

</body>
</html>
```